# Django: tests.py adds project name to class

Tags: python, django

In my views.py I have a piece of code that checks if a model inherits from an other model.

```
 def inherits_from_animal(some_animal):
     return Animal in inspect.getmro(some_animal)
```

Now in my views.py this works but in my tests it's failing because the name of the project gets added to the class name.

So if I have a project named zoo and an app named animals it looks like:

views.py:

```
<class 'animals.models.Animal'>
```

tests.py:

```
<class 'zoo.animals.models.Animal'>
```

Could anybody explain why this is happening and how I could fix it?

**Update:**
Seems to only be happening to an abstract model.

Comment: For me, the project name is always in the class name, abstract or not. Wonder where those class names are determined?

Comment: How do you import Animal in views.py/tests.py? How do you reference the `animals` app in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @emulbreh seems you were thinking in the right direction. I only added the app name to INSTALLED_APP without the project name. Now all the models have are prepended with the name of the project. Seems to only happen with the django_nose test runner though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `manage.py`. If you put django apps inside other packages you should use their fully qualified module name for imports and as a corrolary in INSTALLED_APPS.

It still works if you omit the parent package name, because manage.py temporarily hacks sys.path to import the module that contains the settings module. Then nose does its own import magic and is unable to reproduce the manage.py hack.

I'd recommend to use django-admin.py instead of manage.py as it does not do any import tricks.
There is no concept of a project in django. Just treat everything as plain python packages and control your PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 1):

the inspect module is doing probably something hinky.

Python has the builtin function [issubclass()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#issubclass) for just this occasion!

```
def inherits_from_animal(some_animal):
    return issubclass(some_animal, Animal)
```

although i dont see why you couldnt just use issubclass wherever you are using inherits_from_animal now ;)

Comment: Actually issubclass is also failing in my tests.py

Comment: does it fail when you run it in django shell?

Comment: gah! sorry, i swapped the order of the arguments. try it now.

Comment: The problem was the naming in INSTALLED_APPS.